# mysql query is slow, adding indexes doesnt work

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 100k+ rows but my queries are slow (they take about 3 seconds).

I tried making an index like this but this doesn't seem to do anything.

```
ALTER TABLE pm ADD INDEX (sender,reciever)
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT id,message FROM pm WHERE reciever = '28075' OR sender = '28075'
```

That takes 3 seconds more or less.

Explain of table PM

''[image: EXPLAIN OF TALBE PM]

EXPLAIN of the query:

[image: to]

SHOW CREATE TABLE PM:

```
`CREATE TABLE `pm` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `datetime` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `reciever` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `users` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `readm` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `forOp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bussy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bericht` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
 `aantal` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `users` (`users`(191)),
 KEY `sender` (`sender`,`reciever`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1637118 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
```

Comment: HINT: check your indexes order, i think move sender column before reciever like `WHERE  sender = '28075' OR reciever = '28075'` second use `EXPLAIN` and either query using index or not for `OR`

Comment: Prepend the word EXPLAIN to you query and share the output here so we can see the query plan.

Comment: *"HINT: check your indexes order, i think move sender column before reciever like WHERE sender = '28075' OR reciever = '28075'"* @devpro  that statement/hint is not right..  See [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) explains how multiple column indexes are used by MySQL also see a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u7zJyLxe69sjsbT7nVwSyc/0)

Comment: @RaymondNijland: check screen shot.

Comment: *"check screen shot"* @devpro mine comment was meant to be read in general as your hint is wrong..  Topicstarter please do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE pm` and post that instead of a PHPMyAdmin image..

Comment: *"I tried making an index like this but this doesn't seem to do anything."*  Yes indexes in MySQL are costs based, MySQL most likely saw based on data distribution a FULL scan was faster and ignored the index..  What does   `SELECT  COUNT(reciever = 28075) / COUNT(*) FROM pm` and `SELECT COUNT(sender = 28075)  / COUNT(*) FROM pm`  give as results? Those queries should calculate  Index Selectivity and those values should ideally be closer to 1 then 0

Comment: @RaymondNijland `SELECT COUNT(reciever = 28075) / COUNT(*) FROM pm`

`COUNT(reciever = 28075) / COUNT(*)`
1.0000

`SELECT COUNT(sender = 28075) / COUNT(*) FROM pm`

`COUNT(sender = 28075) / COUNT(*)`
1.0000

Comment: i think in this case would go for `KEY sender (sender),
 KEY reciever (reciever)`  and a query rewite `SELECT
    id
  , message
FROM pm
WHERE reciever = '28075'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id
  , message
FROM pm
WHERE sender = '28075'`  as `OR` tends to optimize bad in MySQL....

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks, query is now 0.0013 seconds, thats a huge difference

Comment: i think the Index Selectivity caculation was wrong which i give in the other comment i think it should have been `SELECT COUNT(sender = 28075 OR reciever = 28075 ) / COUNT(*) ... ` blame it to the leak of coffee... Using a self join was also a option now i think about it annyhow problem solved

Answer (score 2):

The reason the query could not use an index is that it uses `OR`, and your index can't be used to match the `receiver` (as a compound index requires that you match the leftmost column before matching the second one)

MySQL 5 added an `index_merge` which allows using multiple indexes for the same query, so if you have separate indexes on `sender` and `receiver` it could pick those.

An alternative would be to rewrite the query to use `UNION` and again use separate indexes instead of compound one:

```
SELECT id,message FROM pm WHERE reciever = '28075'
UNION 
SELECT id,message FROM pm WHERE sender = '28075'
```

You can read more [at this article](https://www.techfounder.net/2008/10/15/optimizing-or-union-operations-in-mysql/)

Comment: You also need an index on `(reciever)` or `(reciever, <other columns>)`. Otherwise the first query will perform a full table scan, and you win nothing.